# Login to Grails Application using Google account and OAuth plugin

Tags: grails, oauth-2.0

I am trying to create a login page in which users can use their Google account to login in. I am using grail's 'oauth:2.6.1' plugin to achieve this.
I registered an app in google and got client id and secret, but I am not able to use that in my config.groovy. It throws the below exception:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - OAuthException occurred when processing request: [GET]    /MyApp/oauth/google/authenticate - parameters:
redirectUrl: 
Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Consumer is not registered: 553489692142-6l3c1tk0l0rtc7dgebeijbh5jtcv4tor.apps.googleusercontent.com
'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Consumer is not registered: 553489692142-6l3c1tk0l0rtc7dgebeijbh5jtcv4tor.apps.googleusercontent.com
'
    Line | Method
->>   41 | extract         in org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     27 | extract         in     ''
|     64 | getRequestToken in org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl
|     40 | getRequestToken in     ''
|     45 | getRequestToken in     ''
|     78 | authenticate    in    uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthController
|    198 | doFilter . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter        in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

My grails version is 2.5. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Have a look to [this blog post](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/integration-with-google-using-grails-oauth-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your credentials for google api are bad. Check your key/secret in google developer console.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what's wrong in that.                                                        Client ID for web application

Client ID 
553489692142-6l3c1tk0l0rtc7dgebeijbh5jtcv4tor.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address 
553489692142-6l3c1tk0l0rtc7dgebeijbh5jtcv4tor@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret 
fnIlgy0dw7u_V4lXZlsRVHtQ
Redirect URIs 
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/oauth/google/callback
JavaScript origins 
http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Did you check your URLs in google dev console? I think you missconfigured this. Maybe you use https instead of http or the reverse.

Comment: I tried with Redirect URIs : https://localhost:8080/MyApp/google/success. The client Id got updated. But still the same exception occurs.

Comment: What about your JavaScript origins? You should use the same http or https port like you configured in dev console. You should specifie this explicitly. I think Redirect URLs make less difference but JavaScript origins do.

Comment: And you try to login over https and not http?

Comment: You can try to test your settings when you just use some browser REST plugins link RESTClient for Firefox. What do you need is this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer